B2C Custom Policy, send over strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber as the phone string
When an Azure B2C User goes through my User Journey, one of the step that they must go through is to set up their MFA. One option is using their phone number. I want to capture the phone number that they use, along with their Azure B2C objectId. I was able to get their objectId correctly, but the phone number is coming back weird. Here is how the TechnicalProfile is set up:
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-sendObjectIdAndMFAPhoneNumber">
    <DisplayName>Validate user for migration</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl"> {BaseURL}/objectId/{objectId}/strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber/{strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber}</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Url</Item>
    <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" Required="true" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>

After hitting my endpoint with the objectId and the strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber, the data for the objectId comes back correctly. The strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber comes back as the field name itself, inside curly braces, exactly like so: {strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber}.
I tried using Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber, but it was the same exact issue, the field name came back as the string inside the curly braces: Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber}.
I was expecting that the number itself, ie +1 8001112222 would have came back as the value.

Ensure the strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber claim is properly defined and resolved before sending it to the REST API endpoint. Check endpoint configuration and enable logging for debugging to know more details.
